# AttributeError: module 'cherrypy' has no attribute 'expose'

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have installed cherrypy using pip within a virtualenv and run the first tutorial:

```
import cherrypy


class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

It throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/wc/playground/scripts/cherrypy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cherrypy
  File "C:\wc\playground\scripts\cherrypy.py", line 4, in <module>
    class HelloWorld(object):
  File "C:\wc\playground\scripts\cherrypy.py", line 5, in HelloWorld
    @cherrypy.expose
AttributeError: module 'cherrypy' has no attribute 'expose'
```

Anyone have any idea about why?

Comment: Are you calling your script with virtualenv activated?

Comment: Yes, I definitely am! Its strange though: if I open python through cmd and execute each line individually, it works. If its run as a script, this error appears.